# Find the Git commit that added a file matching a glob pattern

Tags: git

Is there a Git command that would allow finding the first commit that added a file matching a pattern?

For example, let's say I want to find the commit that first added a file matching the pattern `path/prefix/*/subpath/*`. I found out that it can be done by combining `git rev-list` to find commits that added files under a fixed path (e.g., `path/prefix`), iterate the commits to list the files they added via `git diff-tree`, and use `grep` to find files matching the given pattern (e.g., `/subpath/`):

```sh
for COMMIT in $(git rev-list \
                    --reverse \
                    --topo-order \
                    HEAD \
                    path/prefix)
do
  git diff-tree \
    --diff-filter A \
    --name-only \
    --no-commit-id \
    -r "${COMMIT}" |
  grep -q "/subpath/" && echo "${COMMIT}" && break
done
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" is in the eye of the ... runner, but you can do this with `git log` and either `head` or `tail`.  We start with the basic:

```
git log <options> --diff-filter=A --format=%H -- 'path/prefix/*/subpath/*'
```

which dumps out *all* the hash IDs (add `--topo-order` if desired, add `--reverse` if desired).  Then we just snip out all but the last (if not using `--reverse`) or first (if using `--reverse`):

```
(the git log command) | tail -n 1
```

This will generally be *faster* since `git log` can quickly eliminate the non-candidates, but it could sometimes be slower perhaps.

Comment: Thanks! `git --no-pager log --diff-filter=A --format=%H --reverse --topo-order -- "path/prefix/*/subpath/*" | head -n 1` works slightly faster in my case and is more compact.